# How to replace substrings 000-000 with new GUIDs

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I need to replace all "0000-000" strings with new GUIDs. So each "0000-000" in the string should have a new GUID. So far, I've been able to replace all with one 1 new GUID. Here is a very basic code:

```
private string ReplaceGuids(string xmlContent)
{
    string fakeGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    xmlContent = @"<!--<workflow id=""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"">--><!--<workflow id=""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"">-->";

    //Method 1: replaces all 000000-00000 with the same new GUID
    xmlContent = xmlContent.Replace(fakeGuid, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper());

    //Method 2: also replacs all 0000-00000 with the same GUID
    int pos = -1;
    do
    {
        pos = xmlContent.IndexOf(fakeGuid);
        if (pos > 0)
        {
            xmlContent = xmlContent.Replace(fakeGuid, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper());
        }

    } while (pos > 0);

    return xmlContent;
}
```

I've used RegEx before but not sure how to make each 000-000 to get different  new GUIDs. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Regex.Replace` method with the overload that takes a match evaluator, so that you can create a new replacement string for each match.

As you are replacing a specific string, use the `Regex.Escape` method to escape any characters in it that would have a special meaning as a pattern.

```
xmlContent = Regex.Replace(
  xmlContent,
  Regex.Escape(fakeGuid),
  m => Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()
);
```

Your second method would also work if you didn't use `Replace` to put the GUID in the string, but use `Substring` to get the parts before and after the part to replace:

```
int pos = -1;
do {
  pos = xmlContent.IndexOf(fakeGuid);
  if (pos > 0) {
    xmlContent =
      xmlContent.Substring(0, pos) +
      Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() +
      xmlContent.Substring(pos + fakeGuid.Length);
  }
} while (pos > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^0{8}-0{4}-0{4}-0{4}-0{12}$
```

or (for only "0" and "-"):

```
^[0-]+$
```

With flag MultiLine

[See match demo](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=XlswLV0rJA%3D%3D&t=MDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwDQoxMjMxMjMxMi0xMjMzLTM0MjMtMTIzMS0zMTI0MjM0MzQyMzQNCjEyMzEyMzEyLTEyMzMtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTMxMjQyMzQzNDIzNA0KMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwDQoxMjMxMjMxMi0xMjMzLTM0MjMtMTIzMS0zMTI0MjM0MzQyMzQ%3D&op=2)

[See replace test](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.replace?p=XlswLV0rJA%3D%3D&t=MDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwDQoxMjMxMjMxMi0xMjMzLTM0MjMtMTIzMS0zMTI0MjM0MzQyMzQNCjEyMzEyMzEyLTEyMzMtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTMxMjQyMzQzNDIzNA0KMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwDQoxMjMxMjMxMi0xMjMzLTM0MjMtMTIzMS0zMTI0MjM0MzQyMzQ%3D&r=TkVXR1VJRA%3D%3D&op=2)